# Using an array with SHGetFolderPath

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My code is:

```
int copyme() {

    TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    std::array<std::string, 16> locations = { "CSIDL_APPDATA","CSIDL_CDBURN_AREA","CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA","CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY","CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS","CSIDL_COMMON_MUSIC","CSIDL_COMMON_PICTURES","CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS","CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU","CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP","CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES","CSIDL_COMMON_VIDEO","CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY","CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE","CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA","CSIDL_PERSONAL", };

    for (auto& location : locations) {

        (SHGetFolderPath(NULL,
            location | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
            NULL,
            0,
            szPath)
    }
```

I'm trying to call `SHGetFolderPath` with CSIDLs from an array, but according to the documentation:

> nFolder [in]
>
> Type: int
>
> A CSIDL value that identifies the folder whose path is to be retrieved. Only real folders are valid. If a virtual folder is specified, this function fails. You can force creation of a folder by combining the folder's CSIDL with CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE.

So only `int` can be used.  Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Forget about the iteration. Try to call the function successfully with a single value. I've no idea why you think you can bitwise OR a string and an integer! Read the documentation properly. Read it carefully. Then pass the CSIDL constants. You will need to perform error checking, which you neglect at present. There's little to be gained from using TCHAR unless you are still targeting Windows 98. Are you? If not use Unicode.

Comment: They aren't strings, they're numbers defined in `ShlObj.h`; e.g. `#define CSIDL_APPDATA 0x001a`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? (AKA What do you expect to happen when you run this code?) Obviously it's not a simple fetch of the known folder path.

Comment: @theB: since the code is using `CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE`, I assume it just wants to ensure the folders actually exist and it doesn't care about the actual paths.

Answer (score 4):

As the [`SHGetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) documentation clearly states, the `nFolder` parameter is an integer, not a string.  [`CSIDL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) values are numeric IDs, not strings (their human-readable names are `#define`'d in `shlobj.h`).

So, just change your array from `std::string` to `int`, and remove the quote characters around the CSIDL names:

```
int copyme()
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    std::array<int, 16> locations = {
        CSIDL_APPDATA, CSIDL_CDBURN_AREA, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY,
        CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, CSIDL_COMMON_MUSIC, CSIDL_COMMON_PICTURES, CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS,
        CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU, CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP, CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES, CSIDL_COMMON_VIDEO,
        CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, CSIDL_PERSONAL};

    for (auto location : locations)
    {
        SHGetFolderPath(NULL,
            location | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
            NULL,
            0,
            szPath);
    }
```